# Why Android Gradle 3.2.1 only work on Android Studio 4.0.1 or below?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mobile

After upgrading my android studio to v.4.0.1, my application with gradle 3.2.1 doesn't work. My application doesn't use androidx, it still old version. Any one have same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the version of gradle you are using since that version of Android relies on 4.0+

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4-0-0